# Why is sound not working in XP when playing music?

Tags: windows, audio, system-sounds

I am using Windows XP 32-bit. When I test the speakers in the audio control panel, everything works fine. But when I play some music, I can't hear any sound from my speakers.

What could be the problem and how can I fix this?

Comment: could you clarify a bit please? How do you play the music, do you not hear the music or other sounds while you play the music?

Comment: sure i have tried to open music with different players like Windows media player and vnc players usually but no audio sound at al :(  but while checking the speaker i could hear the sound

Answer (score 0):

try playing a video on YouTube. If you get sound output from your speaker, then there is something wrong with the music file you are playing.